# SQL Injection prevention with dynamic SQL ALTER USER query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is this good way to prevent sql injection in dynamic sql alter user query:

```
BEGIN
    z_ident :=  DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(ident);    
    z_pass := DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(password); 
    z_sql := 'alter user ' || z_ident || ' identified by ' || z_pass;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE z_sql;
END;
```

Because, sometimes you have function to generate random password with " character, and when you do:

```
SELECT DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME('"asd') FROM DUAL;
```

You get an ORA-06512 / ORA-06502 exception.

Comment: Personally, I would avoid using double-quotes in an Oracle db password, so that would mean updating the function that generates the password. DBMS_ASSERT is the best way to avoid SQL Injection in this case, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to prevent SQL injection only on database level. Once they got there, they mostly already got you. You should use parameters, mask input and remove bad characters already in the layer above. Tools(Frameworks?) like Entity Framework automatically remove dangerous characters.

Using `DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME` is doing very well here, but I'd recommend doing this as well in the layers above.

General rule (that you follow here):
**Use security mechanisms that are established and proven, don't reinvent them!**

Moreover, a statement like

```
select * from users where username = 'IAm"WayUp';
```

is absolutely legal and not dangerous.

And how do you call the function/procedure in the DB? You're vulverable there as well, aren't you?.

Comment: "You shouldn't try to prevent SQL injection on database level" ... yes you absolutely should!!! By not ensuring the data that is going to be used in a dynamic SQL, you leave yourself wide open to SQL injection. Using DBMS_ASSERT to sanitize the data is the preferred method of doing that, within the database level!